# referencing a cell to a range in different worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I reference a cell to a range in excel?

For eg: I want to reference cell `A1` of *Sheet1* to Range `A1:A10` of *Sheet3*.

- Only one cell in the range `A1:A10` will have value in it or no cell will have values.
- But no two cells in the range will have value.

So if Cell `A6` of Range `A1:A10` in *Sheet3* has this value then I want to display that value in Cell `A1` of *Sheet1*.

How to best acoomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet3!A1:A10<>""),Sheet3!A1:A10),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

If only one cell will ever have a value, you can just use `=sum(Sheet3!A1:A10)`. It will return a value of `0` if nothing is filled in.

Comment: This answer assumes numeric values.

If you are only looking at a small range of alpha-numeric values such as 10 cells, I would go with `=concatenate(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10)` or `=A1&A2&A3&A4&A5&A6&A7&A8&A9&A10` works as well. If anymore then this, I would use an equation that is more programmatic such as teylyn's answer. All about keeping it simple.